# Apache directive to point subdomains to a different folder than the primary domain

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, lamp

I would like Apache to serve subdomains of a site to a different directory, here is what I have tried (didn't work)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/other_directory/
        ServerName sub.maindomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
       ServerName maindomain.com
       ServerAlias www.maindomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The above gives an error that basically says that you can't have it both ways and it will default to the first directive.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have your `000-default` file ?

Comment: I have never messed with 000-default file before... I am on CentOS6 where is that supposed to go?